# How to concatenate 2 multidimensional arrays matching criteria in JS?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

How can I add 02 elements/columns to array1, if a couple of criteria are met in the following scenario?

```
noPedido = 1000
let ordersData = sheet1.getRange(2, 1, sheet1.getLastRow(), sheet1.getLastColumn()).getValues();
let deliveryData = sheet2.getRange(2, 1, sheet2.getLastRow(), 13).getValues();
for (let a = deliveryData .length - 1; a >= 0; a--) {
      for (let n = ordersData .length - 1; n >= 0; n--) {
        if (deliveryData[a][12] == noPedido && ordersData[n][11] == noPedido
          && deliveryData[a][1] == ordersData[n][1]) {
          let row = n + 2;
          let qtds = [deliveryData [a][4], deliveryData [a][5]];
          sheet1.getRange(row, 24, 1, 2).setValues([qtds]);//Adds found data to adjacent columns
        }
      }
    }
```

If I had a 2D array `ordersData`, which I do, I wouldn't have to get the values so I could get its rows in `sheet1`, where I'm setting the values.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your goal. So, when my proposed modification is not useful, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect? By this, I would like to modify it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From `sheet1.getRange(row, 24, 1, 2).setValues([qtds]);//Adds found data to adjacent columns` in your script, if you want to add `qtds` to the same row of `ordersData[n]`, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
sheet1.getRange(row, 24, 1, 2).setValues([qtds]);
```

#### To:

```
ordersData[n] = [...ordersData[n], ...qtds];
```

- In this modification, the values of `qtds` is added to the same row of `ordersData[n]`.

Comment: This increases performance nicely here! Thank you! Some folks downvote the questions, without understanding the positive impact it will have depite how simple the question may be to them. Sad! Thanks for usually taking the time to help!

Comment: @santosOnit Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.